# how to retrieve data using two while loops

Tags: php

The first query works fine and it retrieves the class id but I have a problem with the second query as it does not retrieve the child name

```
<select name="child-name" id="Schild">
<?php
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $sql1 = "SELECT Class_id FROM Class WHERE Emp_id = '$username'";
    $result = mysqli_query($database,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($database));

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $classID = $row['Class_id'];
        $sql2 = "SELECT Name FROM Children WHERE Class_id = '$classID'";
        $result2 = mysqli_query($database,$sql2) or die(mysqli_error($database));
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
?>
    <option><?php echo $row['Name'];?></option>  

<?php 
        }
?> 
</select>
```

Comment: sql injections for the win

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements as described in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: You are using `$row` in both resultset fetches. Therefore destroying it for the outer loop

Comment: you use the same row variable. just have another variable name. also turn error reporting

Comment: ... whereas I'm still trying to work out what *"restive data"* is ... is it a bit fidgety? Aaaaaaah *retrieve* maybe?

Comment: seems OP is AWOL

Comment: @CD001 I think he means _retrieve_

Comment: @RiggsFolly - yeah, there's a pending grammar edit on the post now from   *Akin*; needs a couple more approvals

Comment: @CD001 yup I approved already I am afraid, still need 1 more

Answer (score 1):

You are using $row in both resultset fetches. Therefore destroying it for the outer loop

While testing always add these lines, specially if you are testing on a live/hosted server where error reporting will almost definitely be turned off

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
    ini_set('log_errors',1); 
    error_reporting(E_ALL); 
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
?>

<select name="child-name" id="Schild">
<?php
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $sql1 = "SELECT Class_id FROM Class WHERE Emp_id = '$username'";
    $result = mysqli_query($database,$sql1) or die(mysqli_error($database));
    // Late breaking fix             ^^^^

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $classID = $row['Class_id'];
        $sql2 = "SELECT Name FROM Children WHERE Class_id = '$classID'";
        $result2 = mysqli_query($database,$sql2) or die(mysqli_error($database));
        while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
    // fix    ^^^^^
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row2['Name'];?>"><?php echo $row2['Name'];?></option>  
<?php 
    // fix             ^^^^^
        }
?> 
</select>
<?php
    // also add terminator for first while loop
    }
?>
```

Comment: Any different results?

Comment: See suggested error reporting additions to make to your script

Comment: Are u sure is the children equal that class id? @SamahAbuSaud did you try run the query from php my admin and hand code the id?

Comment: yes, the class id retrieved successfully, but the problem is retrieving the names with that specify class id

Comment: does a name with that class id exist?

Comment: @RiggsFolly you made a error here : `$sql1 =....` then `$result = mysqli_query($database,$sql)`  the query never runs

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile No you just spotted the other error that I missed. Thank you. So much for the first query working!! I wonder what code they are really running???

Comment: @RiggsFolly I believe that was the reason he's second query failed. Op was lying when he said he got results from the first query, that's impossible 1st query never execute

Comment: @SamahAbuSaud Please check the code again. I have made another fix

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Got go now. Maybe catch you later

Comment: @RiggsFolly.. I added the new part that you add in the code but nothing happen